# Random Path with Several Trajectories (for loop/array not right?)

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to code a random path with several trajectories. My code is below and calculates a path, but the for loop does not create multiple different paths. Rather, it plots the same path n times on top of itself. I want to be a able to graph n number of different paths from within the same for loop, store the values in a single array, then graph them next to each other. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
from numpy.random import randint
n = 1000
moves = randint(0, 2, size=n)
y = 0
x = [y]
n2 = 5

for t in range(n2):
    for i in moves:
        if i == 1:
            y = y + 1
        if i == 0:
            y = y - 1
        x.append(y)
    plt.plot(x)
    y = 0
    x = [y]
```

Comment: `moves = randint(0, 2, size=n)`: `randint` doesn't take that many arguments

Comment: What's the definition of that `randint`? It's not the usual one from the `random` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: thanks- should have included the library import. apologies. updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a different path on each iteration of the loop then you should call `randint` inside of the loop, and calculate the path there

```
from numpy.random import randint
n = 1000
n2 = 5

for t in range(n2):
    moves = randint(0, 2, size=n)
    y = 0
    x = [y]
    for i in moves:
        if i == 1:
            y = y + 1
        if i == 0:
            y = y - 1
        x.append(y)
    plt.plot(x)
    y = 0
    x = [y]
```

If you want to store all the computed paths, you can store them in a list or array:

```
from numpy.random import randint
n = 1000
n2 = 5
paths = []  # use something like numpy.empty((n2, n)) to use an array

for t in range(n2):
    moves = randint(0, 2, size=n)
    y = 0
    x = [y]
    for i in moves:
        if i == 1:
            y = y + 1
        if i == 0:
            y = y - 1
        x.append(y)
    paths.append(x)  # use something like paths[t] = x with an array
    plt.plot(x)
    y = 0
    x = [y]
```

Then `paths[i]` would contain the i-th computed path, and `paths[i][j]` (or `paths[i, j]` with an array) the j-th position of the i-th path.

Yet another alternative would be to store all the paths in a linear list (or a one-dimensional array) one after the other, so `paths[:n]` would be the first path, then `paths[n:2*n]`, `paths[2*n:3*n]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot- runs perfect and I appreciate the explanation. Marked as answered.